# Vertical Menu Weird Padding

Tags: html, css, padding

I am trying to make a simple vertically aligned menu that has a width of 100%. However, there is some weird padding on the left that prevents the menu from stretching the whole 100%.

HTML

```
<div class="sidecontent">
     <nav class="sidemenu">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Long Sleeve T's</a></li>   
             <li><a href="#">Hoodies</a></li>   
             <li><a href="#">Towels</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Design Your Own</a></li>
         </ul>
     </nav>
 </div>
```

CSS

```css
div.sidecontent {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
nav.sidemenu {
    width: 100%;
}
nav.sidemenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}
nav.sidemenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
}
nav.sidemenu ul li:first-child {
    border-top: 0;
}
nav.sidemenu ul li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
nav.sidemenu ul li a:link, nav.sidemenu ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #4C4C4C;
    padding: 28px 0;
}
nav.sidemenu ul li a:hover, nav.sidemenu ul li a:active {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awcPd/)

Comment: Please consider tagging HTML and CSS for code highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Solution
nav.sidemenu ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding:0;
            }
```

Comment: let me explain, in future always clear the ul or ol default margin and padding if at all you like to margin or padding later. for example nav.sidemenu ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding:0;padding-left:5px;
            }

Answer (score 0):

It's the unordered list indent, try adding this to your css:

```
ul {
list-style:none;
padding-left:0;
}​
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to Chrome's HTML inspector, the `ul` object appears to have sever hidden characteristics:

```
ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px; //this is what's bothering you
}
```

Hence you want to set the `padding-left` to `0 px` for `ul` objects:

```
nav.sidemenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0; //this is what I added
}
```

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/awcPd/5/

Comment: Ah that would indeed be the problem. It's working now. Thanks!